# Is it possible to prevent a XAML element with an x:Name from being accessible outside of the class in which it is defined?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, scope

Say I have a control with a label, and I want to be able to reference that label from code-behind. I can accomplish this by giving the label an `x:Name`:

```
<UserControl x:Class=...>
    <Label x:Name="someLabel">Foo</Label>
    ....
</UserControl>
```

Unfortunately, now I can do this in a different class:

```
`someUserControl.someLabel.Content = ...`
```

Is there any way to limit access to the `Label` to the class in which it is defined? I.e., I would still be able to reference it in the UserControl's code-behind, but nowhere else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default they will be internal, and the documentation says you can use the [x:FieldModifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970905.aspx) attribute to make it public. Regardless of what the docs say, you can do `x:FieldModifier="private"` for C# to make the field private.

Comment: A bit confused by the wording. (and not know much og FieldModifier). Did you mean can't make it private or Can make it public or private instead of the default?

Comment: @Rune - Updated to clarify what I meant.